# How to have AdSense Ads only match the content of the page and not user history?

Tags: google-adsense

We have a classified ads website.

We would like to display Google AdSense Ads based on the content and not on the user's history/profile. It would perform way better and be more accurate to the users' intentions.

Long time ago it was possible. Today it seems to be only possible with Google AdSense "Custom Search Ads".

Is there a solution/possibility with Google AdSense "Ads" or an other Google AdSense "product/program on request"? (They often have not communicated products/programs that are activated by request only)

Comment: Why do you say it would perform better?   Google uses ads that target users because they have been shown to work so well.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Our metrics. :) Imagine a user looking for an appartement. He will have a higher probability to click on ads related to the current page content (for exemple a moving company, a painter, etc) than on an advertising based on his "history" of searches (usually in other contexts) like baby diapers (because he bought some a few hours ago).